# NHibernate Concurrency Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, sqlite, concurrency

Over the weekend I realized that an application I'm working on which uses NHibernate as an ORM to a sqlite database has a concurrency issue.

I'm essentially looping through a collection in javascript and executing the following:

```
var item = new Item();
item.id = 1;
item.name = 2;
$.post("Item/Save", $.toJSON(item), function(data, testStatus) {
  /*User can be notified that the item was saved successfully*/
}, "text");
```

And my server code looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Save()
{
    string json = Request.Form[0];
    var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(JsonItem));
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json));
    JsonItem item = (JsonItem)serializer.ReadObject(memoryStream);
    memoryStream.Close();

    SaveItem(item);
    return Content("success");
}
```

The concurrency issue obviously occurs in the loop calling Save() for each element iterated, but I'm not sure how to accommodate for and prevent this.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: The code is there, I'm not sure why you can't see it.  I introduced with the line "I'm essentially looping through a collection in javascript and executing the following"

Comment: I do understand it now. Why don't you post all objects in the same request? And I can imagine several concurrency problems, which one do you mean?

Comment: That is the solution I have ended up implementing.  I have never had a problem with concurrency problems before thus I am not sure how many or which types would have been relevant here.  I have been doing some homework learning more about the issues but if you have any links to resources to help me out I would really appreciate it so I can be prepared in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the concurrency issue?

I didn't understand your problem with concurrency.

Comment: if you iterate the collection, AND in the postback you reload the window... hmmm... there is a potential problem here. The first postback will throw away any pending work, refreshing completely the page.

Suggestion: don't iterate, send the complete collection in one Ajax call.

Comment: The postback wasn't actually there, I copied some old code from a textfile...oops.   Anyway, I once upon a time thought that sending the entire collection would be a tricky procedure, but a half hour coding has shown me otherwise.  Thanks for your solution.